# Strapi Lifestyle Hook Race Condition

Tags: javascript, strapi

I have a strapi/nextjs blog that consists of collection types called Article. I wrote a lifestyle hook to update the count everytime the article is fetched. The issue is that both fetching the article and updating the view count triggers the lifestyle hook, and I can't figure out how to separate the two. Here is the hook:

```
// location: './api/article/content-types/article/lifeycles.js'

module.exports = {
  async afterFindOne(event) {
    if (event) {
      const { result } = event;
      const currentViews = parseInt(result.views);
      const newView = currentViews+1
      strapi.query("api::article.article").update({
        where: { id: result.id.toString() },
        data: {
          views: newView,
        },
      });
    }
  },
};
```

I'd like to avoid custom controllers if I can and Im not sure there's anything in the "event" parameter that will allow you to distinguish what triggered the hook.